# Woocommerce "your cart is currently empty" but only outside of preview mode? (custom checkout form)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

In WordPress I'm using an "in-page" checkout custom form where people fill the form directly IN the page where the product is displayed and they can pay directly from there without going throught the cart page.

It works fine while I'm in preview mode and in the same Chrome window: the order get processed, I can pay with whatever and everything just works. However if I open the page in another window or browser (or my phone), after I press the button to confirm the order, I get sent to the "your cart is empty" page and no order is processed.
It's really weird that it works only in preview mode.

I already cleared all possible caches from my hosting domain and even cleared the cookies for that site from my browser, however it still doesn't work.

This is the custom code for the checkout form if it can help:

```
<?php
// In page checkout form
setlocale(LC_TIME, "it_IT");

$productId = $GLOBALS['inpage_form_product'];
$options = $GLOBALS['inpage_form_options'];

wp_enqueue_style('inpage-form', get_template_directory_uri() . ($options['inpage_form_style'] ?? '/inpage-form.css'));
wp_enqueue_script('inpage-form', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/inpage-form.js');

$product = wc_get_product($productId);
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();

$variations = array_map(function ($variation) use ($options) {
    return [
        'id' => $variation['variation_id'],
        'label' => $variation['attributes']['attribute_quantita'],
        'price' => $variation['display_price'],
        'regular_price' => $variation['display_regular_price'],
        'quantity' => strip_tags($variation['variation_description']),
        'highlight' => $options['highlight_label_' . $variation['variation_id']] ?? false,
        'highlight_color' => $options['highlight_label_color_' . $variation['variation_id']] ?? false,
    ];
}, $variations);

$initialVariation = $variations[0];

function formatPrice($price)
{
    echo number_format($price, 2, ',', '') . '€';
}

WC()->cart->empty_cart();
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($productId, 1, $initialVariation['id']);

if(class_exists('WC_Gateway_Stripe')) {
    $stripe = new WC_Gateway_Stripe();

    $suffix = defined('SCRIPT_DEBUG') && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';
    wp_register_style('stripe_styles', plugins_url('assets/css/stripe-styles.css', WC_STRIPE_MAIN_FILE), [], WC_STRIPE_VERSION);
    wp_enqueue_style('stripe_styles');

    wp_register_script('stripe', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/', '', '3.0', true);
    wp_register_script('woocommerce_stripe', plugins_url('assets/js/stripe' . $suffix . '.js', WC_STRIPE_MAIN_FILE), ['jquery-payment', 'stripe'], WC_STRIPE_VERSION, true);
    wp_register_script('woocommerce_gateway_stripe', plugins_url('assets/js/stripe' . $suffix . '.js', WC_STRIPE_MAIN_FILE), ['jquery-payment', 'stripe'], WC_STRIPE_VERSION, true);

    wp_localize_script(
        'woocommerce_stripe',
        'wc_stripe_params',
        apply_filters('wc_stripe_params', $stripe->javascript_params())
    );

    $stripe->tokenization_script();
    wp_enqueue_script('woocommerce_stripe');
}


wp_enqueue_script('wc-country-select');
wp_enqueue_script('selectWoo');
wp_enqueue_style('select2');

$shippingMethods = WC()->shipping()->get_packages()[0]['rates'];
$chosenMethod = isset(WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[0]) ? WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[0] : '';

function business_day($days, $abbrv = false)
{
    if($abbrv) {
        return utf8_encode(strtolower(strftime('%a %e. %m.', strtotime("+$days weekdays"))));
    }
    return utf8_encode(strtolower(strftime('%A', strtotime("+$days weekdays"))));
}

function add_delivery_payment_info()
{
    printf('<div class="inpage-form__delivery_payment">');
    printf('<div class="inpage-form__delivery_payment__wrapper">');
    printf('<div>');
    printf('<div class="inpage-form__delivery_payment__title">Oggi non paghi niente!</div>');
    printf('<div class="inpage-form__delivery_payment__description">Paghi alla consegna </div>');
    printf('</div>');
    printf('
    <svg enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="512" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m19 4.86-8.991 4.383-3.501-1.701-1.458-.711-4.05-1.971 8.991-4.374 3.834 1.864 1.53.738z" fill="#ffa726"/><path d="m9.99 19.779-9.49-4.939v-9.48l9.49 4.37z" fill="#ffcc80"/><path d="m19.5 5.36v9.48l-9.49 4.939v-10.049z" fill="#ffb74d"/><path d="m17.5 23.4c-.142 0-.283-.044-.403-.133-.558-.415-5.447-4.141-5.447-7.302 0-1.855 1.514-3.364 3.375-3.364.957 0 1.848.401 2.475 1.074.627-.673 1.518-1.074 2.475-1.074 1.861 0 3.375 1.509 3.375 3.364 0 3.161-4.89 6.888-5.447 7.302-.12.089-.261.133-.403.133z" fill="#f44336"/><path d="m17.5 24c-.157 0-.314-.05-.447-.148-.62-.46-6.053-4.601-6.053-8.114 0-2.061 1.682-3.738 3.75-3.738 1.063 0 2.054.446 2.75 1.194.696-.748 1.687-1.194 2.75-1.194 2.068 0 3.75 1.677 3.75 3.738 0 3.513-5.433 7.653-6.053 8.113-.133.099-.29.149-.447.149zm-2.75-10.5c-1.241 0-2.25 1.004-2.25 2.238 0 2.142 3.276 5.191 5 6.564 1.724-1.374 5-4.427 5-6.564 0-1.234-1.009-2.238-2.25-2.238-.897 0-1.707.527-2.062 1.343-.238.547-1.137.547-1.375 0-.356-.816-1.166-1.343-2.063-1.343z"/><path d="m10.007 10.5c-.278 0-.545-.155-.675-.422-.181-.372-.026-.821.346-1.002l9.244-4.5c.234-.114.507-.099.726.039.219.136.352.377.352.635v4c0 .414-.336.75-.75.75s-.75-.336-.75-.75v-2.801l-8.166 3.975c-.105.052-.217.076-.327.076z"/><path d="m9.25 20c-.125 0-.25-.03-.366-.096l-8.5-4.75c-.237-.132-.384-.383-.384-.654v-9.25c0-.258.133-.499.353-.636.218-.138.493-.153.726-.039l9.244 4.5c.373.181.527.63.346 1.002-.182.373-.632.525-1.002.346l-8.167-3.974v7.61l8.116 4.536c.362.201.491.658.289 1.021-.137.245-.393.384-.655.384z"/><path d="m.75 6c-.277 0-.544-.155-.674-.422-.181-.372-.026-.821.346-1.002l9.244-4.5c.207-.101.449-.101.656 0l9.256 4.5c.373.181.527.63.346 1.002s-.629.529-1.002.346l-8.928-4.34-8.916 4.34c-.105.052-.217.076-.328.076z"/><path d="m5.25 11.99c-.414 0-.75-.336-.75-.75v-3.8c0-.283.16-.542.413-.67l9.09-4.581c.369-.186.82-.038 1.007.333.186.37.038.821-.333 1.007l-8.677 4.373v3.338c0 .414-.336.75-.75.75z"/></svg>');
    printf('</div>');
    printf('</div>');
}

add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'add_delivery_payment_info');

?>
<div class="inpage-form" data-product-id="<?php echo $productId; ?>">
    <div class="inpage-form__form-card">
        <h4>Modulo d’ordine</h4>
        <div class="inpage-form__total">
            <span class="inpage-form__regular-price"><?php formatPrice($initialVariation['regular_price']); ?></span>
            <span class="inpage-form__price"><?php formatPrice($initialVariation['price']); ?></span>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="inpage-form__countdown">
            <svg enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="512" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="512"
                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor">
                <path d="m6.5 19h-2c-.276 0-.5-.224-.5-.5s.224-.5.5-.5h2c.276 0 .5.224.5.5s-.224.5-.5.5z"/>
                <path d="m22.75 19h-1.25c-.276 0-.5-.224-.5-.5s.224-.5.5-.5h.835l.674-3.592c-.009-1.838-1.579-3.408-3.509-3.408h-3.283l-1.591 7h2.874c.276 0 .5.224.5.5s-.224.5-.5.5h-3.5c-.152 0-.296-.069-.391-.188-.095-.118-.131-.274-.097-.422l1.818-8c.052-.229.254-.39.488-.39h3.682c2.481 0 4.5 2.019 4.5 4.5l-.759 4.092c-.044.237-.25.408-.491.408z"/>
                <path d="m19.5 21c-1.378 0-2.5-1.121-2.5-2.5s1.122-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.121 2.5 2.5-1.122 2.5-2.5 2.5zm0-4c-.827 0-1.5.673-1.5 1.5s.673 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5-.673 1.5-1.5-.673-1.5-1.5-1.5z"/>
                <path d="m8.5 21c-1.378 0-2.5-1.121-2.5-2.5s1.122-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.121 2.5 2.5-1.122 2.5-2.5 2.5zm0-4c-.827 0-1.5.673-1.5 1.5s.673 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5-.673 1.5-1.5-.673-1.5-1.5-1.5z"/>
                <path d="m6.5 10h-4c-.276 0-.5-.224-.5-.5s.224-.5.5-.5h4c.276 0 .5.224.5.5s-.224.5-.5.5z"/>
                <path d="m6.5 13h-5c-.276 0-.5-.224-.5-.5s.224-.5.5-.5h5c.276 0 .5.224.5.5s-.224.5-.5.5z"/>
                <path d="m6.5 16h-6c-.276 0-.5-.224-.5-.5s.224-.5.5-.5h6c.276 0 .5.224.5.5s-.224.5-.5.5z"/>
                <path d="m14 19h-3.5c-.276 0-.5-.224-.5-.5s.224-.5.5-.5h3.101l2.272-10h-11.373c-.276 0-.5-.224-.5-.5s.224-.5.5-.5h12c.152 0 .296.069.391.188.095.118.131.274.097.422l-2.5 11c-.052.229-.255.39-.488.39z"/>
            </svg>
            <div>
                 <div class="inpage-form__countdown__title">Affrettati con l'acquisto</div>
                <div class="inpage-form__countdown__description">Se ordini entro
                    <time class="inpage-form__countdown_hook">30:00</time>
                    minuti riceverai <strong><?php //echo business_day(2); ?></strong></div>
                <div class="inpage-form__countdown__description">Se ordini entro
                    <time class="inpage-form__countdowner_hook">30:00</time>
                    minuti riceverai <strong><? //php echo business_day(2); ?></strong></div>
            </div>
        </div>-->
        <?php if(count($variations) > 1): ?>
        <ul class="inpage-form__options">
            <?php foreach ($variations as $variation) :
                $singlePrice = $variation['price'] / (float) $variation['quantity'];
            ?>
                <li class="inpage-form__option <?php echo $variation['highlight'] ? 'inpage-form__option-highlight' : ''; ?>">
                    <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="quantity"
                            id="option-<?php echo $variation['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $variation['id']; ?>"
                            data-regular-price="<?php echo $variation['regular_price']; ?>"
                            data-price="<?php echo $variation['price']; ?>"
                    />
                    <?php if ($variation['highlight']) { ?>
                        <div class="inpage-form__option-top" <?php echo $variation['highlight_color'] ? 'style="background-color:'. $variation['highlight_color'].'"' : ''; ?>>
                            <?php echo $variation['highlight']; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <label for="option-<?php echo $variation['id']; ?>">
                        <span class="inpage-form__quantity"><?php echo $variation['quantity']; ?><small>x</small></span>
                        <span class="inpage-form__option-main">
                        <span class="inpage-form__single-price"><?php formatPrice($singlePrice); ?></span>
                        <span class="inpage-form__quantity-info">a pezzo</span>
                    </span>
                    </label>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="inpage-form__checkout">
            <form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout"
                  action="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_checkout_url()); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
                    <p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required validate-email" id="billing_email_field"
                       data-priority="110">
                        <input type="email" class="input-text" name="billing_email" id="billing_email"
                               placeholder="Indirizzo email " value="" autocomplete="email username"/>
                        <label for="billing_email" class="">Indirizzo email</label>
                    </p>
                    <p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required validate-phone" id="billing_phone_field"
                       data-priority="100">
                        <input type="tel" class="input-text "
                               name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone"
                               placeholder="Telefono" value=""
                               autocomplete="tel"/>
                        <label for="billing_phone" class="">Telefono</label>
                    </p>
                    <div class="inpage-form__form-row-online">
                        <p class="form-row form-row-first validate-required" id="billing_first_name_field"
                           data-priority="10">
                            <input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name"
                                   placeholder="Nome" value="" autocomplete="given-name"/>
                            <label for="billing_first_name" class="">Nome</label>
                        </p>
                        <p class="form-row form-row-last validate-required" id="billing_last_name_field"
                           data-priority="20">
                            <input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_last_name" id="billing_last_name"
                                   placeholder="Cognome" value="" autocomplete="family-name"/>
                            <label for="billing_last_name" class="">Cognome</label>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                

                <?php
                    if($options['insurance_product'] ?? false) :
                      $insuranceProduct = wc_get_product($options['insurance_product']);
                    ?>
                    <label class="inpage-form__insurance inpage-form__extras" data-product-id="<?php echo $options['insurance_product']; ?>">
                        <svg id="color" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="512" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m23.491 1.826-5.25-1.786c-.156-.054-.326-.054-.482 0l-5.25 1.786c-.305.103-.509.388-.509.71v4.018c0 4.904 5.474 7.288 5.707 7.387.094.039.193.059.293.059s.199-.02.293-.06c.233-.099 5.707-2.482 5.707-7.386v-4.018c0-.322-.204-.607-.509-.71z" fill="#4caf50"/><path d="m21.286 5.618-2.75 3.5c-.168.214-.417.351-.688.377l-.098.005c-.237 0-.469-.084-.65-.241l-1.75-1.5c-.42-.359-.469-.991-.108-1.41.359-.419.991-.467 1.409-.108l.958.821 2.105-2.679c.341-.434.969-.511 1.404-.168.434.34.51.969.168 1.403z" fill="#fff"/><path d="m18 0h-.019c-.075.002-.15.015-.222.04l-5.25 1.786c-.305.103-.509.388-.509.71v4.018c0 4.904 5.474 7.288 5.707 7.387.094.039.193.059.293.059v-4.532c-.05.013-.101.022-.152.027l-.098.005c-.237 0-.469-.084-.65-.241l-1.75-1.5c-.42-.359-.469-.991-.108-1.41.197-.23.477-.349.759-.349.23 0 .462.079.649.24l.958.821.392-.498z" fill="#429846"/><path d="m16.001 6c-.282 0-.562.118-.76.349-.36.419-.312 1.051.108 1.41l1.75 1.5c.182.157.414.241.651.241l.098-.005c.051-.005.102-.014.152-.027v-2.905l-.392.498-.958-.82c-.188-.162-.419-.241-.649-.241z" fill="#dedede"/><path d="m22 17.5c-2 0-6 2.531-8 2.531s-4.25-1.531-4.25-1.531 2.693.5 4.25.5 2-.531 2-1.25c0-1.75-2.973-2.022-4.476-2.25-1.477-.822-3.037-1.333-5.481-1.54-.015.142-.037.284-.077.425l-2.009 7.08c2.275 1.036 6.986 2.535 9.043 2.535 3 0 11-4 11-5s-1-1.5-2-1.5z" fill="#ffcc80"/><path d="m3.5 22h-2.75c-.414 0-.75-.336-.75-.75v-8.5c0-.414.336-.75.75-.75 3.505 0 5.138 1.216 5.205 1.268.242.185.349.498.27.792l-2 7.386c-.089.327-.386.554-.725.554z" fill="#2196f3"/><path d="m22 17.5c-2 0-6 2.531-8 2.531s-4.25-1.531-4.25-1.531l-4.472-.944-1.053 3.89c-.011.042-.026.081-.044.12 2.348 1.028 6.828 2.434 8.819 2.434 3 0 11-4 11-5s-1-1.5-2-1.5z" fill="#deb26f"/><path d="m0 16.442v4.808c0 .414.336.75.75.75h2.75c.296 0 .56-.173.681-.435.018-.038.032-.078.044-.12l1.053-3.89z" fill="#1d83d4"/></svg>
                        <div class="inpage-form__insurance__wrapper">
                            <?php
                                if($insuranceProduct->get_regular_price() !== $insuranceProduct->get_price()) {
                                    printf('<div class="inpage-form__insurance__title">Assicura il tuo pacchetto a soli <del>%s</del> %s</div>', wc_price($insuranceProduct->get_regular_price()), wc_price($insuranceProduct->get_price()));
                                } else {
                                    printf('<div class="inpage-form__insurance__title">Assicura il tuo pacchetto a soli %s</div>', wc_price($insuranceProduct->get_price()));
                                }
                            ?>
                            <div class="inpage-form__insurance__description">Se il prodotto nella confezione è danneggiato, te ne invieremo uno nuovo senza alcuna domanda.</div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="insurance_enable">
                    </label>
                    <?php
                    endif
                ?>

                <?php
                    if($options['gift_product'] ?? false) :
                      $giftProduct = wc_get_product($options['gift_product']);
                    ?>
                    <label class="inpage-form__gift inpage-form__extras" data-product-id="<?php echo $options['gift_product']; ?>">
                        <svg id="Capa_1" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="#fbe77b"><path d="m214.374 64.52s-64.52-64.52-139.447-64.52c-43.707 0-60.358 29.138-60.358 58.276s17.691 58.276 49.951 58.276h149.854z"/><path d="m214.374 64.52s-64.52-64.52-139.447-64.52c-43.707 0-60.358 29.138-60.358 58.276s17.691 58.276 49.951 58.276h149.854z"/><path d="m297.626 64.52s64.52-64.52 139.447-64.52c43.707 0 60.358 29.138 60.358 58.276s-17.691 58.276-49.951 58.276h-149.854z"/></g><path d="m492 199.805h-472c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20v-43.252c0-11.046 8.954-20 20-20h472c11.046 0 20 8.954 20 20v43.252c0 11.046-8.954 20-20 20z" fill="#fb636f"/><path d="m484.943 116.553v83.252h6.453c11.379 0 20.604-9.225 20.604-20.604v-42.045c0-11.379-9.225-20.604-20.604-20.604h-6.453z" fill="#fa4954"/><path d="m193.561 116.553h124.878v83.252h-124.878z" fill="#fbe77b"/><path d="m464.943 512h-417.886c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20v-292.195h457.886v292.195c0 11.046-8.954 20-20 20z" fill="#fb636f"/><path d="m27.057 199.805h457.886v24.976h-457.886z" fill="#fa4954"/><path d="m214.374 199.805h83.252v312.195h-83.252z" fill="#fbe77b"/><path d="m214.374 199.805h83.252v24.976h-83.252z" fill="#fcdd2e"/><path d="m326.764 95.74c-4.333 0-8.045-2.65-9.611-6.416 2.685-.986 5.58-1.951 8.585-2.798 4.107-1.158 6.498-5.426 5.341-9.533s-5.425-6.499-9.533-5.341c-1.773.5-3.505 1.035-5.189 1.589v-24.848c-11.859 9.256-18.732 16.127-18.732 16.127v52.033h149.855c17.376 0 30.516-8.46 38.951-20.813z" fill="#fcdd2e"/><path d="m195.642 48.393v24.848c-1.683-.554-3.416-1.089-5.189-1.589-4.104-1.157-8.375 1.233-9.533 5.341-1.157 4.107 1.233 8.375 5.341 9.533 2.998.845 5.895 1.812 8.584 2.8-1.566 3.765-5.278 6.413-9.61 6.413h-159.666c8.435 12.353 21.575 20.813 38.951 20.813h149.854v-52.032s-6.873-6.871-18.732-16.127z" fill="#fcdd2e"/><path d="m297.626 116.553h-83.252v-52.602c0-7.732 6.268-14 14-14h55.252c7.732 0 14 6.268 14 14z" fill="#fbe77b"/><path d="m214.374 95.74h83.252v20.813h-83.252z" fill="#fcdd2e"/></svg>
                        <div class="inpage-form__gift__wrapper">
                            <div class="inpage-form__gift__title">Abbiamo un regalo per te!</div>
                            <?php
                                if($giftProduct->get_regular_price() !== $giftProduct->get_price()) {
                                    printf('<div class="inpage-form__gift__description">Prodotto esclusivo per te a solo <del>%s</del> <strong>%s</strong></div>', wc_price($giftProduct->get_regular_price()), wc_price($giftProduct->get_price()));
                                } else {
                                    printf('<div class="inpage-form__gift__description">Prodotto esclusivo per te a solo <strong>%s</strong></div>', wc_price($giftProduct->get_price()));
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="gift_enable">
                        <div type="button" class="inpage-form__gift__btn">
                            Aggiungi
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <?php
                    endif
                ?>

                <h3>Metodo di pagamento</h3>
                <div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">
                    <?php woocommerce_checkout_payment(); ?>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--    --><?php //WC()->checkout()->checkout_form_billing(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    wc_load_cart();
    Use this code use to refresh cart

<?php
// In page checkout form
setlocale(LC_TIME, "it_IT");

$productId = $GLOBALS['inpage_form_product'];
$options = $GLOBALS['inpage_form_options'];

wp_enqueue_style('inpage-form', get_template_directory_uri() . ($options['inpage_form_style'] ?? '/inpage-form.css'));
wp_enqueue_script('inpage-form', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/inpage-form.js');

$product = wc_get_product($productId);
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();

$variations = array_map(function ($variation) use ($options) {
    return [
        'id' => $variation['variation_id'],
        'label' => $variation['attributes']['attribute_quantita'],
        'price' => $variation['display_price'],
        'regular_price' => $variation['display_regular_price'],
        'quantity' => strip_tags($variation['variation_description']),
        'highlight' => $options['highlight_label_' . $variation['variation_id']] ?? false,
        'highlight_color' => $options['highlight_label_color_' . $variation['variation_id']] ?? false,
    ];
}, $variations);

$initialVariation = $variations[0];

function formatPrice($price)
{
    echo number_format($price, 2, ',', '') . '€';
}
wc_load_cart();
WC()->cart->empty_cart();
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($productId, 1, $initialVariation['id']);

if(class_exists('WC_Gateway_Stripe')) {
    $stripe = new WC_Gateway_Stripe();

    $suffix = defined('SCRIPT_DEBUG') && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';
    wp_register_style('stripe_styles', plugins_url('assets/css/stripe-styles.css', WC_STRIPE_MAIN_FILE), [], WC_STRIPE_VERSION);
    wp_enqueue_style('stripe_styles');

    wp_register_script('stripe', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/', '', '3.0', true);
    wp_register_script('woocommerce_stripe', plugins_url('assets/js/stripe' . $suffix . '.js', WC_STRIPE_MAIN_FILE), ['jquery-payment', 'stripe'], WC_STRIPE_VERSION, true);
    wp_register_script('woocommerce_gateway_stripe', plugins_url('assets/js/stripe' . $suffix . '.js', WC_STRIPE_MAIN_FILE), ['jquery-payment', 'stripe'], WC_STRIPE_VERSION, true);

    wp_localize_script(
        'woocommerce_stripe',
        'wc_stripe_params',
        apply_filters('wc_stripe_params', $stripe->javascript_params())
    );

    $stripe->tokenization_script();
    wp_enqueue_script('woocommerce_stripe');
}


wp_enqueue_script('wc-country-select');
wp_enqueue_script('selectWoo');
wp_enqueue_style('select2');

$shippingMethods = WC()->shipping()->get_packages()[0]['rates'];
$chosenMethod = isset(WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[0]) ? WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[0] : '';

function business_day($days, $abbrv = false)
{
    if($abbrv) {
        return utf8_encode(strtolower(strftime('%a %e. %m.', strtotime("+$days weekdays"))));
    }
    return utf8_encode(strtolower(strftime('%A', strtotime("+$days weekdays"))));
}

function add_delivery_payment_info()
{
    printf('<div class="inpage-form__delivery_payment">');
    printf('<div class="inpage-form__delivery_payment__wrapper">');
    printf('<div>');
    printf('<div class="inpage-form__delivery_payment__title">Oggi non paghi niente!</div>');
    printf('<div class="inpage-form__delivery_payment__description">Paghi alla consegna </div>');
    printf('</div>');
    printf('
    <svg enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="512" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m19 4.86-8.991 4.383-3.501-1.701-1.458-.711-4.05-1.971 8.991-4.374 3.834 1.864 1.53.738z" fill="#ffa726"/><path d="m9.99 19.779-9.49-4.939v-9.48l9.49 4.37z" fill="#ffcc80"/><path d="m19.5 5.36v9.48l-9.49 4.939v-10.049z" fill="#ffb74d"/><path d="m17.5 23.4c-.142 0-.283-.044-.403-.133-.558-.415-5.447-4.141-5.447-7.302 0-1.855 1.514-3.364 3.375-3.364.957 0 1.848.401 2.475 1.074.627-.673 1.518-1.074 2.475-1.074 1.861 0 3.375 1.509 3.375 3.364 0 3.161-4.89 6.888-5.447 7.302-.12.089-.261.133-.403.133z" fill="#f44336"/><path d="m17.5 24c-.157 0-.314-.05-.447-.148-.62-.46-6.053-4.601-6.053-8.114 0-2.061 1.682-3.738 3.75-3.738 1.063 0 2.054.446 2.75 1.194.696-.748 1.687-1.194 2.75-1.194 2.068 0 3.75 1.677 3.75 3.738 0 3.513-5.433 7.653-6.053 8.113-.133.099-.29.149-.447.149zm-2.75-10.5c-1.241 0-2.25 1.004-2.25 2.238 0 2.142 3.276 5.191 5 6.564 1.724-1.374 5-4.427 5-6.564 0-1.234-1.009-2.238-2.25-2.238-.897 0-1.707.527-2.062 1.343-.238.547-1.137.547-1.375 0-.356-.816-1.166-1.343-2.063-1.343z"/><path d="m10.007 10.5c-.278 0-.545-.155-.675-.422-.181-.372-.026-.821.346-1.002l9.244-4.5c.234-.114.507-.099.726.039.219.136.352.377.352.635v4c0 .414-.336.75-.75.75s-.75-.336-.75-.75v-2.801l-8.166 3.975c-.105.052-.217.076-.327.076z"/><path d="m9.25 20c-.125 0-.25-.03-.366-.096l-8.5-4.75c-.237-.132-.384-.383-.384-.654v-9.25c0-.258.133-.499.353-.636.218-.138.493-.153.726-.039l9.244 4.5c.373.181.527.63.346 1.002-.182.373-.632.525-1.002.346l-8.167-3.974v7.61l8.116 4.536c.362.201.491.658.289 1.021-.137.245-.393.384-.655.384z"/><path d="m.75 6c-.277 0-.544-.155-.674-.422-.181-.372-.026-.821.346-1.002l9.244-4.5c.207-.101.449-.101.656 0l9.256 4.5c.373.181.527.63.346 1.002s-.629.529-1.002.346l-8.928-4.34-8.916 4.34c-.105.052-.217.076-.328.076z"/><path d="m5.25 11.99c-.414 0-.75-.336-.75-.75v-3.8c0-.283.16-.542.413-.67l9.09-4.581c.369-.186.82-.038 1.007.333.186.37.038.821-.333 1.007l-8.677 4.373v3.338c0 .414-.336.75-.75.75z"/></svg>');
    printf('</div>');
    printf('</div>');
}

add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'add_delivery_payment_info');

?>
<div class="inpage-form" data-product-id="<?php echo $productId; ?>">
    <div class="inpage-form__form-card">
        <h4>Modulo d’ordine</h4>
        <div class="inpage-form__total">
            <span class="inpage-form__regular-price"><?php formatPrice($initialVariation['regular_price']); ?></span>
            <span class="inpage-form__price"><?php formatPrice($initialVariation['price']); ?></span>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="inpage-form__countdown">
            <svg enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="512" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="512"
                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor">
                <path d="m6.5 19h-2c-.276 0-.5-.224-.5-.5s.224-.5.5-.5h2c.276 0 .5.224.5.5s-.224.5-.5.5z"/>
                <path d="m22.75 19h-1.25c-.276 0-.5-.224-.5-.5s.224-.5.5-.5h.835l.674-3.592c-.009-1.838-1.579-3.408-3.509-3.408h-3.283l-1.591 7h2.874c.276 0 .5.224.5.5s-.224.5-.5.5h-3.5c-.152 0-.296-.069-.391-.188-.095-.118-.131-.274-.097-.422l1.818-8c.052-.229.254-.39.488-.39h3.682c2.481 0 4.5 2.019 4.5 4.5l-.759 4.092c-.044.237-.25.408-.491.408z"/>
                <path d="m19.5 21c-1.378 0-2.5-1.121-2.5-2.5s1.122-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.121 2.5 2.5-1.122 2.5-2.5 2.5zm0-4c-.827 0-1.5.673-1.5 1.5s.673 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5-.673 1.5-1.5-.673-1.5-1.5-1.5z"/>
                <path d="m8.5 21c-1.378 0-2.5-1.121-2.5-2.5s1.122-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.121 2.5 2.5-1.122 2.5-2.5 2.5zm0-4c-.827 0-1.5.673-1.5 1.5s.673 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5-.673 1.5-1.5-.673-1.5-1.5-1.5z"/>
                <path d="m6.5 10h-4c-.276 0-.5-.224-.5-.5s.224-.5.5-.5h4c.276 0 .5.224.5.5s-.224.5-.5.5z"/>
                <path d="m6.5 13h-5c-.276 0-.5-.224-.5-.5s.224-.5.5-.5h5c.276 0 .5.224.5.5s-.224.5-.5.5z"/>
                <path d="m6.5 16h-6c-.276 0-.5-.224-.5-.5s.224-.5.5-.5h6c.276 0 .5.224.5.5s-.224.5-.5.5z"/>
                <path d="m14 19h-3.5c-.276 0-.5-.224-.5-.5s.224-.5.5-.5h3.101l2.272-10h-11.373c-.276 0-.5-.224-.5-.5s.224-.5.5-.5h12c.152 0 .296.069.391.188.095.118.131.274.097.422l-2.5 11c-.052.229-.255.39-.488.39z"/>
            </svg>
            <div>
                 <div class="inpage-form__countdown__title">Affrettati con l'acquisto</div>
                <div class="inpage-form__countdown__description">Se ordini entro
                    <time class="inpage-form__countdown_hook">30:00</time>
                    minuti riceverai <strong><?php //echo business_day(2); ?></strong></div>
                <div class="inpage-form__countdown__description">Se ordini entro
                    <time class="inpage-form__countdowner_hook">30:00</time>
                    minuti riceverai <strong><? //php echo business_day(2); ?></strong></div>
            </div>
        </div>-->
        <?php if(count($variations) > 1): ?>
        <ul class="inpage-form__options">
            <?php foreach ($variations as $variation) :
                $singlePrice = $variation['price'] / (float) $variation['quantity'];
            ?>
                <li class="inpage-form__option <?php echo $variation['highlight'] ? 'inpage-form__option-highlight' : ''; ?>">
                    <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="quantity"
                            id="option-<?php echo $variation['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $variation['id']; ?>"
                            data-regular-price="<?php echo $variation['regular_price']; ?>"
                            data-price="<?php echo $variation['price']; ?>"
                    />
                    <?php if ($variation['highlight']) { ?>
                        <div class="inpage-form__option-top" <?php echo $variation['highlight_color'] ? 'style="background-color:'. $variation['highlight_color'].'"' : ''; ?>>
                            <?php echo $variation['highlight']; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <label for="option-<?php echo $variation['id']; ?>">
                        <span class="inpage-form__quantity"><?php echo $variation['quantity']; ?><small>x</small></span>
                        <span class="inpage-form__option-main">
                        <span class="inpage-form__single-price"><?php formatPrice($singlePrice); ?></span>
                        <span class="inpage-form__quantity-info">a pezzo</span>
                    </span>
                    </label>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="inpage-form__checkout">
            <form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout"
                  action="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_checkout_url()); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
                    <p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required validate-email" id="billing_email_field"
                       data-priority="110">
                        <input type="email" class="input-text" name="billing_email" id="billing_email"
                               placeholder="Indirizzo email " value="" autocomplete="email username"/>
                        <label for="billing_email" class="">Indirizzo email</label>
                    </p>
                    <p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required validate-phone" id="billing_phone_field"
                       data-priority="100">
                        <input type="tel" class="input-text "
                               name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone"
                               placeholder="Telefono" value=""
                               autocomplete="tel"/>
                        <label for="billing_phone" class="">Telefono</label>
                    </p>
                    <div class="inpage-form__form-row-online">
                        <p class="form-row form-row-first validate-required" id="billing_first_name_field"
                           data-priority="10">
                            <input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name"
                                   placeholder="Nome" value="" autocomplete="given-name"/>
                            <label for="billing_first_name" class="">Nome</label>
                        </p>
                        <p class="form-row form-row-last validate-required" id="billing_last_name_field"
                           data-priority="20">
                            <input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_last_name" id="billing_last_name"
                                   placeholder="Cognome" value="" autocomplete="family-name"/>
                            <label for="billing_last_name" class="">Cognome</label>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                

                <?php
                    if($options['insurance_product'] ?? false) :
                      $insuranceProduct = wc_get_product($options['insurance_product']);
                    ?>
                    <label class="inpage-form__insurance inpage-form__extras" data-product-id="<?php echo $options['insurance_product']; ?>">
                        <svg id="color" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="512" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m23.491 1.826-5.25-1.786c-.156-.054-.326-.054-.482 0l-5.25 1.786c-.305.103-.509.388-.509.71v4.018c0 4.904 5.474 7.288 5.707 7.387.094.039.193.059.293.059s.199-.02.293-.06c.233-.099 5.707-2.482 5.707-7.386v-4.018c0-.322-.204-.607-.509-.71z" fill="#4caf50"/><path d="m21.286 5.618-2.75 3.5c-.168.214-.417.351-.688.377l-.098.005c-.237 0-.469-.084-.65-.241l-1.75-1.5c-.42-.359-.469-.991-.108-1.41.359-.419.991-.467 1.409-.108l.958.821 2.105-2.679c.341-.434.969-.511 1.404-.168.434.34.51.969.168 1.403z" fill="#fff"/><path d="m18 0h-.019c-.075.002-.15.015-.222.04l-5.25 1.786c-.305.103-.509.388-.509.71v4.018c0 4.904 5.474 7.288 5.707 7.387.094.039.193.059.293.059v-4.532c-.05.013-.101.022-.152.027l-.098.005c-.237 0-.469-.084-.65-.241l-1.75-1.5c-.42-.359-.469-.991-.108-1.41.197-.23.477-.349.759-.349.23 0 .462.079.649.24l.958.821.392-.498z" fill="#429846"/><path d="m16.001 6c-.282 0-.562.118-.76.349-.36.419-.312 1.051.108 1.41l1.75 1.5c.182.157.414.241.651.241l.098-.005c.051-.005.102-.014.152-.027v-2.905l-.392.498-.958-.82c-.188-.162-.419-.241-.649-.241z" fill="#dedede"/><path d="m22 17.5c-2 0-6 2.531-8 2.531s-4.25-1.531-4.25-1.531 2.693.5 4.25.5 2-.531 2-1.25c0-1.75-2.973-2.022-4.476-2.25-1.477-.822-3.037-1.333-5.481-1.54-.015.142-.037.284-.077.425l-2.009 7.08c2.275 1.036 6.986 2.535 9.043 2.535 3 0 11-4 11-5s-1-1.5-2-1.5z" fill="#ffcc80"/><path d="m3.5 22h-2.75c-.414 0-.75-.336-.75-.75v-8.5c0-.414.336-.75.75-.75 3.505 0 5.138 1.216 5.205 1.268.242.185.349.498.27.792l-2 7.386c-.089.327-.386.554-.725.554z" fill="#2196f3"/><path d="m22 17.5c-2 0-6 2.531-8 2.531s-4.25-1.531-4.25-1.531l-4.472-.944-1.053 3.89c-.011.042-.026.081-.044.12 2.348 1.028 6.828 2.434 8.819 2.434 3 0 11-4 11-5s-1-1.5-2-1.5z" fill="#deb26f"/><path d="m0 16.442v4.808c0 .414.336.75.75.75h2.75c.296 0 .56-.173.681-.435.018-.038.032-.078.044-.12l1.053-3.89z" fill="#1d83d4"/></svg>
                        <div class="inpage-form__insurance__wrapper">
                            <?php
                                if($insuranceProduct->get_regular_price() !== $insuranceProduct->get_price()) {
                                    printf('<div class="inpage-form__insurance__title">Assicura il tuo pacchetto a soli <del>%s</del> %s</div>', wc_price($insuranceProduct->get_regular_price()), wc_price($insuranceProduct->get_price()));
                                } else {
                                    printf('<div class="inpage-form__insurance__title">Assicura il tuo pacchetto a soli %s</div>', wc_price($insuranceProduct->get_price()));
                                }
                            ?>
                            <div class="inpage-form__insurance__description">Se il prodotto nella confezione è danneggiato, te ne invieremo uno nuovo senza alcuna domanda.</div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="insurance_enable">
                    </label>
                    <?php
                    endif
                ?>

                <?php
                    if($options['gift_product'] ?? false) :
                      $giftProduct = wc_get_product($options['gift_product']);
                    ?>
                    <label class="inpage-form__gift inpage-form__extras" data-product-id="<?php echo $options['gift_product']; ?>">
                        <svg id="Capa_1" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="#fbe77b"><path d="m214.374 64.52s-64.52-64.52-139.447-64.52c-43.707 0-60.358 29.138-60.358 58.276s17.691 58.276 49.951 58.276h149.854z"/><path d="m214.374 64.52s-64.52-64.52-139.447-64.52c-43.707 0-60.358 29.138-60.358 58.276s17.691 58.276 49.951 58.276h149.854z"/><path d="m297.626 64.52s64.52-64.52 139.447-64.52c43.707 0 60.358 29.138 60.358 58.276s-17.691 58.276-49.951 58.276h-149.854z"/></g><path d="m492 199.805h-472c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20v-43.252c0-11.046 8.954-20 20-20h472c11.046 0 20 8.954 20 20v43.252c0 11.046-8.954 20-20 20z" fill="#fb636f"/><path d="m484.943 116.553v83.252h6.453c11.379 0 20.604-9.225 20.604-20.604v-42.045c0-11.379-9.225-20.604-20.604-20.604h-6.453z" fill="#fa4954"/><path d="m193.561 116.553h124.878v83.252h-124.878z" fill="#fbe77b"/><path d="m464.943 512h-417.886c-11.046 0-20-8.954-20-20v-292.195h457.886v292.195c0 11.046-8.954 20-20 20z" fill="#fb636f"/><path d="m27.057 199.805h457.886v24.976h-457.886z" fill="#fa4954"/><path d="m214.374 199.805h83.252v312.195h-83.252z" fill="#fbe77b"/><path d="m214.374 199.805h83.252v24.976h-83.252z" fill="#fcdd2e"/><path d="m326.764 95.74c-4.333 0-8.045-2.65-9.611-6.416 2.685-.986 5.58-1.951 8.585-2.798 4.107-1.158 6.498-5.426 5.341-9.533s-5.425-6.499-9.533-5.341c-1.773.5-3.505 1.035-5.189 1.589v-24.848c-11.859 9.256-18.732 16.127-18.732 16.127v52.033h149.855c17.376 0 30.516-8.46 38.951-20.813z" fill="#fcdd2e"/><path d="m195.642 48.393v24.848c-1.683-.554-3.416-1.089-5.189-1.589-4.104-1.157-8.375 1.233-9.533 5.341-1.157 4.107 1.233 8.375 5.341 9.533 2.998.845 5.895 1.812 8.584 2.8-1.566 3.765-5.278 6.413-9.61 6.413h-159.666c8.435 12.353 21.575 20.813 38.951 20.813h149.854v-52.032s-6.873-6.871-18.732-16.127z" fill="#fcdd2e"/><path d="m297.626 116.553h-83.252v-52.602c0-7.732 6.268-14 14-14h55.252c7.732 0 14 6.268 14 14z" fill="#fbe77b"/><path d="m214.374 95.74h83.252v20.813h-83.252z" fill="#fcdd2e"/></svg>
                        <div class="inpage-form__gift__wrapper">
                            <div class="inpage-form__gift__title">Abbiamo un regalo per te!</div>
                            <?php
                                if($giftProduct->get_regular_price() !== $giftProduct->get_price()) {
                                    printf('<div class="inpage-form__gift__description">Prodotto esclusivo per te a solo <del>%s</del> <strong>%s</strong></div>', wc_price($giftProduct->get_regular_price()), wc_price($giftProduct->get_price()));
                                } else {
                                    printf('<div class="inpage-form__gift__description">Prodotto esclusivo per te a solo <strong>%s</strong></div>', wc_price($giftProduct->get_price()));
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="gift_enable">
                        <div type="button" class="inpage-form__gift__btn">
                            Aggiungi
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <?php
                    endif
                ?>

                <h3>Metodo di pagamento</h3>
                <div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">
                    <?php woocommerce_checkout_payment(); ?>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--    --><?php //WC()->checkout()->checkout_form_billing(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but I still get the same issue. I added it where you suggested.